# Testing services with Injector

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a service which is bootstrapped before its dependency and therefore I use `Injector`  to achieve my dependency when it's ready.

```
constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const myService = injector.get(MyService);

    if (myService) {
      this.myService = myService;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 200);
}
```

In my test I have

```
beforeEach(() => {
  return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
       {
          provide: MyClass,
          useClass: MyClass,
          deps: [
            Injector,
          ]
       },
       {
         provide: MyService,
         useValue: myServiceMock
       },
     ]
  });
});
```

The problem is that `TestBed.get(MyService) !== TestBed.get(MyClass).myService`.

By some reason it became two different instances of the same.

How do I make the to be one instance?

Comment: is `TestBed.get(MyClass).myService` undefined?

Comment: Nope it is an instance of MyService

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `fakeAsync`. Since a service uses `setInterval` it eventually resolves in different instances.

Now service assignment looks like this

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
  myClass = TestBed.get(MyClass);
  tick(200);
  myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
}));
```

Additionally I've written a test to ensure same instance

```
expect(myService).toBe((myClass as any).myService)
```